# How to convert JSON data in to python instance and save Django models multiple table with foreginkey (database sqllite)

Tags: python, json, django

I am not able to save with  `id_category = models.ForeignKey`
please help me to solve

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "21": "Categories.parent" must be a "Parents" instance.
```

**View.py**

```
def GetProducts(request):  
    endpoint = "[https://myurl.net/products/][1]"
    response = requests.request("GET", endpoint)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
        
    for cat in data['Category']:
                        ›
            pro_cat = ProCatData(
                id=cat['id'],
                name=cat['name'],
                image=cat['image'],
            )
            pro_cat.save()
    
    for product in data['Products']:
        
            Products = ProductsData(
                id=product['id'],
                name=product['name'],
                id_category=product['id_category'],
                description=product['description'],
                image=product['image'],
            )
            Products.save()
```

**model.py**

```
class ProCatData(models.Model):
    
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class ProductsData(models.Model):
    
    id_category = models.ForeignKey(ProCatData,    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True, blank=True) 
    image = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the primary key of the object, it should be `id_category_id`, so:

```
for product in data['Products']:
    ProductsData.objects.create(
        id=product['id'],
        name=product['name'],
        id_category_id=product['id_category'],
        description=product['description'],
        image=product['image'],
    )
```

But it makes not much sense to give a `ForeignKey` an `id_…` prefix (or `…_id` suffix), since it will fetch the `ProCatData` record, not return the primary key of that object.

Comment: Thanks for your Help, Which is the best solution to collect data from remote Json  data to save Django database as python object please help Mr.Willem

Comment: Done   Mr.Willem thank you so much.